# PHP: ftp_ssl_connect wont work?

Tags: php, ftp

is there anything i've missed on the PHP manual. 
the difference between ftp_connect and ftp_ssl_connect is just the method-name, right.

somehow i'm not able to connect to my ftp-server with ftp_ssl_connect but with ftp_connect everything works fine. I'm using the exact same code.

any ideas what i could do wrong here?

regards matt

Answer (score 0):

This might be causing a problem:

> Since ftp_ssl_connect() requires SSL compiled into PHP, Windows users will need to compile their own PHP this way or download it from another source.

Heres how to do it on linux:

http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/apache-ssl-on-windows/

Heres Windows:

http://www.neilstuff.com/apache/apache2-ssl-windows.htm

The above guides are for setting up SSL (e.g. https ) and may be overkill but they should detail how to compile SSL into PHP.

Comment: thank you, any idea what that means ;) the link doesn't work. i just wanted to have a securer connection to my ftp server.

Comment: what operating system? What http server are you using?